# Chebyshev interpolation vs equally spaced interpolation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Which one is better to use and why? What's the advantage of Chebyshev interpolation over equally spaced interpolation and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With equally spaced nodes, you have [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).  Thus for the function $f(x) = 1/(1 + 25 x^2)$ using equally spaced nodes on the interval $[-1,1]$, as $n$ (the number of nodes) increases the interpolation suffers from wild oscillation near the endpoints.  With Chebyshev nodes, this doesn't happen, in fact if your function $f(x)$ is absolutely continuous the interpolations converge uniformly to $f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$.  So, if you're looking for an interpolation using a large $n$, Chebyshev is a better choice.

Comment: Or use spline interpolation of a sufficient degree to provide  a function with the required number of derivatives.